In WooCommerce how to sort products by category on shop page?
In my woocommerce shop page I use the following function for product sorting by category. The first 4 attributes should be sorted by the newest product first. For the 5th the oldest product should appear first.
In addition I use the StoreCustomizer Plugin. I use the default WooCommerce Widget to filter Products by Attribute.
The following function has no impact at all.
Problem 1: With this function the category 'pentalogs' is on top and not ascending.
Problem 2: The sorting by category is not correct, it should be as in the function.
Thanks for any help :-)
/**
* Add WooCommerce shop page default sorting by category
*/
function custom_product_sorting( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_shop() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );

        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'paintings',
                'orderby'  => 'date',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'limited-edition-art-prints',
                'orderby'  => 'date',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'posters',
                'orderby'  => 'date',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'limited-edition-photos',
                'orderby'  => 'date',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            ),
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'pentalogs',
                'orderby'  => 'date',
                'order'    => 'ASC',
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_product_sorting' );


